# How do I set base URL for all pages of my website?

Tags: php, url

How do I set a base URL for my website and get it to include in every page?

Is there a way for me to easily change a variable to be the base url for the website, such as `<?php $baseurl = "http://www.website.com/website/"; ?>`, and include this on every page so that all CSS, JavaScript, images and PHP includes follow this `$baseurl`?

Comment: Output a `<base>` element  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/base

Comment: You may think this is a good idea, but it probably is not.  First off, unless you want to use PHP to dynamically generate your CSS, you would have to manually change the domain information there.  Second, you will then have to litter your display code with a bunch of `<? echo $baseurl; ?>` for every `href` or `src` on your site.  Why not just use URI's, as they will give you the same exact result (they will all point the resources based on the domain currently used to access the site.)

Comment: Setup an include file called `base.php` for example and put this in every PHP file `include("base.php");` with what `castis` and others wrote, and/or anything else you wish.

Comment: @Fred I just tried this, and it works for everything but the other PHP includes on the page.

Comment: @user2183116 Look at Martin's example and base yourself on that. `Pardon the pun`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can’t make both PHP and client-side assets use the same base URL, unless you use PHP to `echo` a base URL variable or constant to the page.

The usual approach is to have a bootstrap file that you include on every page, and define your base URL and other site-wide variables in there.

**bootstrap.php:**

```
<?php
    define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com');
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
    include('bootstrap.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- // -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- // -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a PHP beginner, what is the benefit of using define() rather than $baseurl = "url"?

Comment: `define()` makes `BASE_URL` globally accessible whereas `$baseurl = "url";` is confined to the inside of whatever function it was defined in.

Comment: One’s a constant and one’s a variable.

Comment: The best answer is down here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481629/how-do-i-set-base-url-for-all-pages-of-my-website#answer-15481676

Answer (score 12):

You may want to take a look at the [html base tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Inside the `<head>` section of your html, put

```
<base href="http://www.website.com/website/">
```

On top of that, you may want to have a `base.php` with default directories and whatnot that you include into your project.

Comment: If I were to do this, for each page would the following be acceptable:     <?php include "baseurl.php"; ?> <head><base href="<?php echo $baseurl"; ?>"></head>

Comment: In all my years making sites I have never heard of this. Bravo!

Answer (score -3):

(xampp), the 
How do I use on the local computer.
folder layout,

http://www.resimagaci.com/img/90rvnrf.png

ust.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
```

alt.php

```
</body>
</html>
```

sabitler.php

```
<?php
#sabitler
define('BASE_URL', 'base-url');
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include 'kutuphane/sabitler.php';
?>
<?php
$ust= BASE_URL . '/kutuphane/ust.php';
$alt= BASE_URL . '/kutuphane/alt.php';
?>
<?php
include ($ust);
?>
<?php
include ($alt);
?>
```