# PHP - Including Files Not accessing Stylec

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having a problem with included files accessing the style sheet in my header.php file.
[image: Screen shot of file structure]

I've created a very basic outline, with just a nav element outline, to see if I could get my inclusions working properly. My index.html has two links:

- one to a page at the root level, test.php
- a second that is within the includes folder, test2.php.

For whatever reason, my test2.php, although including the header.php element, does not bring in any of the styles. Below is my code from test.php and test2.php, what exactly am I missing?

**Test.php**

```
<?php
    include 'includes/header.php';
?>
```

**Test2.php**

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
?>
```

**Style.css**

```
nav {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 95%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**Header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
```

Comment: All set. Added the code

Comment: Try add <base href="/"> inside your head tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `../` to read it's previous containing directory.

It should be like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" />
```

**OR**
You can set the `base_url` of your website, so it will be more flexible even you uploaded it on a hosting.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url().'style/style.css';?>" />
```

You can read more about creating [base_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481629/how-do-i-set-base-url-for-all-pages-of-my-website)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

what is the meaning of :

> My index.html has two links:
>
> one to a page at the root level, test.php
>   a second that is within the includes folder, test2.php.

if that means your **index.php** contain :

```
include 'test.php';
include 'includes/test2.php';
```

you must set your **header.php** stylesheet link base on your **index.php** position/directory, like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
```

because your **index.php** that called **header.php** through **test.php** and **test2.php**.

Comment: by @Roshan 's answer, using base_url() it's good solution to include that header.php from anywhere.